# How to open a url and then check if it is still opened or not in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I saw many methods to open urls in browser in ruby but couldn't find a way to check if its still open or not? I found something here - [watir.com](http://watir.com) but then it seems that it works with `Ruby version >= 1.9.2.` and i have `ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]` so i don't want to change this installation. so is there any way
by which i can open a url and then check if that instance of tab or browser is closed or still open or not???

So, what i wanted to do basically was open a url in a browser so that the server can redirect that url to my script. which script writes the code provided by the server into a file and my ruby application has to read that content of the file. so if i know that the url is closed means that my ruby app can fetch the code from the file now.

Comment: What do you mean by `to open url`?

Comment: I meant open a URL in a browser like "apps.Google.com?code=..." Something like this

Answer (score 0):

You could get the process id. You could then wait for that process to exit, either in your main thread or in another thread.

You can do this by using the process stdlib integration: See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Process.html#method-c-wait

Comment: Okay so let's say I am opening a URL using launchy like launchy.open(URL) now that opens a URL in a browser with many other tabs already open in it. Now how do i get the process Id of that tab in the browser to check if its terminated or not

Comment: No clue, go through the launchy source/wiki and see where it stores the information.

Comment: Nope, no information regarding this is given there thats why asked if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy, not to say impossible. You cannot open the url, the url (uniformed resource locator) is just an address, which your browser uses to request the content of the website (or the resource). The way the Web works is:

1. Guest request the connection to the server (specified by host name of the url, e.g. `stackoverflow.com`) using protocole specified in protocole bit of the url (`http`).
2. Server responds and connection is established
3. Guest sends the request for specific page (the remaining bits of url)
4. Server handles the request and sends the response.
5. Connection is closed.

This means that browser fetches the content of the website and then it has absolutely no interaction with the server once the content is loaded, regardless whether the page is open or not.

The only way I could think of to actually figure out whether the tab is still open or not is to send periodically some AJAX requests to the server, so the server knows the page is still open (or at least that javascript on the page still works). As soon as you didn't receive this update, you can assume the tab or window has been closed.

Comment: I know it is not so easy thats why was looking for third party gems who already managed to achieve this or something like this. So basically what i have to do is open a url in a browser wait for it to load so that the server sends a response ( which is basically a redirect with a code depending on my request ) so that redirect url has a script which writes the code into a file. and i want to know if the server response wrote a code in that file or not so that i can read that code into my ruby app

Comment: @deadman - Could you please update your question with those details, ideally with some examples of what you want to achieve?